# How can I get the maximum sequential in number range?

Tags: sql

I have the specific result above in a select:

```
1   2
1   3
1   5
1   6
1   9
1   10
1   11
1   13
1   14
1   16
1   18
1   20
1   23
1   24
1   25
```

What I want to find is the longest increasing-by-one chain that occurs in the results.

For example, I know that 3 is the maximum length sequence in this number range, coming from the last 3 results (23,24,25 being 3 in a row).

Comment: It is really not clear what you are asking.  For instance "sequential" is an adjective, but you seem to be using it as a noun, so it is very uncertain what you mean by it.

Comment: It's hard to understand what you're asking. How do we interpret your result? What sequence are you looking for? How do you know that 3 is the 'maximum sequential ins'?

Comment: I think what OP is trying to do is find continual 'increasing by 1' sequences within the results. For example the 23,24,25 at the end (which is where the 3 comes from, there's 3 in a row making that chain) - and what they want to find out is how long the longest such chain is in the set of results.

Answer (score 5):

A sequence will have the property that the difference between the number and a sequential ordering will be constant.  In most dialects of SQL, you have a function called `row_number()`, which assigns sequential numbers.

We can use this observation to solve your problem:

```
select (num - seqnum), count(*) as NumInSequence
from (select t.*, row_number() over (order by num) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by (num - seqnum)
```

This gives every sequence.  To get the max, either use `max()` with a subquery or some version of `limit`/`top`.  In SQL Server, for instance, you can do:

```
select top 1 count(*) as NumInSequence
from (select t.*, row_number() over (order by num) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by (num - seqnum)
order by NumInSQuence desc
```

Answer (score 1):

Using this article as the main query:
http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/03/22/find-contiguous-ranges-with-sql/

Just add a column that calculates the difference and select the MAX().

```
SELECT MAX(seq.end - seq.start)
FROM (
select l.id as start,
    (
        select min(a.id) as id
        from sequence as a
            left outer join sequence as b on a.id = b.id - 1
        where b.id is null
            and a.id >= l.id
    ) as end,
from sequence as l
    left outer join sequence as r on r.id = l.id - 1
where r.id is null;
) AS seq
```

Answer (score 0):

@Gordon gave a brilliant and more terse answer.  However, I think a recursive implementation may be useful as well.  Here's a very useful article on recursive CTEs: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243(v=sql.105).aspx

```
-- This first CTE is unnecessary because you presumably already have 
-- your data.  But I wanted to include it to make it easier test.
WITH myNumbers AS (
SELECT *
FROM (
        VALUES
        (2),
        (3),
        (5),
        (6),
        (9),
        (10),
        (11),
        (13),
        (14),
        (16),
        (18),
        (20),
        (23),
        (24),
        (25)
    ) AS x (num)
),
-- To get my sequences I recurse until there is no num + 1 in my set
mySequences AS (
    -- Anchor member definition: Create the first invocation
    SELECT v.num, 0 AS iteration, v.num AS previous, v.num AS start
    FROM myNumbers v
    UNION ALL
    -- Recursive member definition: Recurse until value + 1 does not exist
    SELECT s.num + 1, s.iteration + 1 AS iteration, s.num AS previous, s.start
    FROM mySequences s  -- Notice that we can reference the CTE within itself
    JOIN myNumbers v
        ON v.num = s.num + 1
)
-- I must increment by 1 because I chose to start my recursion at 0
SELECT MAX(iteration + 1)
FROM mySequences
```

That recursive query is similar to writing

```
public int GetSequenceLength(int start, int iteration, int[] myNumbers)
{
    if (myNumbers.Contains(start + 1))
    {
        return GetSequenceLength(start + 1, iteration + 1, myNumbers);
    }
    return iteration;
}
foreach (var myNumber in myNumbers)
{
    var sequenceLength = GetSequenceLength(myNumber, 0, myNumbers) + 1;
    Console.WriteLine(myNumber + " : " + sequenceLength);
}
```